# Anywhere show all the free functions in doxygen documentation?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using doxygen to document my code. I found I can easily find all the classes since there is a tab calles "classes". But I cannot get all the free functions listed together. I have to go to the tab "files" to look for them. Can I put all free functions together in doxygen documentation?

Comment: Now open in the Doxygen bug reporter: [Issue 793084, Freestanding functions do not have a top level tab](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793084).

Comment: Related: [doxygen can't generate extern api in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39353302/673852)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method to group items in pages and the method involve some comment writing from your side. There is not yet available an automated way to group free functions together. 
Still using the grouping option, you can place all items you want into a given page in documentation. More about this and some examples at the Doxygen page:
[Doxygen/manual/grouping](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html)

Comment: Is this still the case? I'd like freestanding functions to get a top-level tab like *Mainpage*, *Namespaces*, *Classes*, and *Files*.