# doxygen can't generate extern api in c

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to document an extern API in an header file as below

```
// bar.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
 * \memberof bar
 * This is foo
 */    
extern int foo();

#define JUNK_A DONT_DOC_IT
#define JUNK_B DONT_DOC_IT

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Function `foo()` is defined is somewhere in archive file and "bar.h" is exposed as user API and I want to document it. But doxygen cannot generate it.
I don't want to enable EXTRACT_ALL because there are some other things I don't want to document it.

As sample code shows I've tried `\memberof` but it's not work. Could someone can help me?

Comment: `\memberof` is related to classes or `structs` (the former not for C code), not files.

Answer (score 1):

As hint from @rveerd, I complete the answer. At first it needs a `\file` commands to document global objects. At this step all objects are documented include those we don't want to document. So we need discard parts we don't need via adding `\cond HIDDEN_SYMBOLS`. The sample code is as below:

```
/** @file test.h */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
 * @brief This is foo
 */    
extern int foo();

/** @cond HIDDEN_SYMBOLS */
#define JUNK_A DONT_DOC_IT
#define JUNK_B DONT_DOC_IT
/** @endcond */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You at least need to document the file itself with `\file` for anything to be generated. Not sure if this is enough to generate documentation for the `extern` function, though.